# How to find out sum of multiplication of 2 column based on value of a third column?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Silly Q, plz help
I am trying to find of Total invested amount for open positions in my PF. which is like
sum( if(G3="","",D3xE3)+if(G4="","",D4xE4)+..+.........)

How to write a formula for the same.

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `SUMPRODUCT()` like-

```
=SUMPRODUCT(D3:D100,E3:E100,G3:G100="")
```